# How can i extract a row begins with a specific name or value?

Tags: r, regex, select, row

I have a data.frame on which i am working on Rstudio.

```
DATA
1.2 yellow
general
white
dog
```

What i need is extract the row containing "1.2 yellow", **and other rows which begins with a particular ID**, and obtaining a result like:

```
DATA
yellow
```

How could i do?
Thank you for your future suggestions.

Comment: if your id is specific use grepl and gsub: `gsub("1.2 ","",DATA[grepl("1.2",DATA$v1),])`, in this case a vector is returned given your dataframe has 1 column. with data defined as `DATA = data.frame(v1=c("1.2 yellow","general","white","dog"))`

Comment: Use sqldf package and write usual sql select